Error checkPrep(mydata, vars, type, remove.calm = FALSE) in R
I get an error
"checkPrep(mydata, vars, type, remove.calm = FALSE)
Can't find the variable(s) ch4"
when using the function trajLevel in OpenAir package (R).
I attach screenshots and my code.
dat <- read.csv("C:/Users/Home/Documents/Old_disser/STATYA/Disser.csv",
                sep=";",header=TRUE,na.strings = "-999.9")
dat$date <- dmy_hm(dat$date)
colnames(dat) <-c("date","wd","ws","co2","ch4","zL")

trajLevel(traj, pollutant = "ch4", 
          statistic = "difference",
          col = c("skyblue", "white", "tomato"), 
          min.bin = 50, 
          border = NA)



I read about the problem when the error occurs due to incorrect reading of the date, but in my case the date has POSIXct format.I checked the structure and data type after reading the file, and did not find any errors. Any other functions in openair work without failures using the .csv file. This problem occurred only with trajLevel function.
My .csv file is

I would be very grateful for advice on solving this problem!

You're running trajLevel on dataframe traj - did you mean to use dataframe dat instead?

@I_O , yes, I planned to use the ch4 variable based on my observations from dataframe "dat".
Am I right in understanding that the variable ch4 for the pollutant should be part of "traj" dataframe?
In that case, how can I get a dataframe that will contain both pollutant and trajectory data? Can I use my ch4 observations and include them ftom "dat" to "traj" dataframe?
Or do I need to download trajectories from some version of HYSPLIT with a chemistry block that already contains pollutant data?

Sadly, I'm not familiar with the OpenAir package. I guess the various steps should be part of the documentation. Regardless, the error message ("can't find variables") suggested you're mistakenly feeding another piece of data to some function than the function expects (a common accident with many data structures lying around in one's workspace).
